# Racket - Retrieving the fractional part of a number

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm looking to retrieving the fractional part of a number. Ie. if i given the number 3.14. I need the output to be 0.14 or 14.

And I need to do this without the using the built-in functions round, floor or ceiling.

Comment: Is this homework? If not, why the restriction on which functions to use?

Answer (score 1):

For a sneaky solution, you can use regular expressions to crop off everything before the dot:

```
(define (fraction-only num)
  (string->number (regexp-replace #rx".*(\\..*)" (number->string num) "\\1")))
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution(provided you can use truncate) is something like this:

```
(define (fract-part n)
    (- n (truncate n)))
```

It will have the usual floating-point math rounding errors though, so `(fract-part 3.14)` returns `0.14000000000000012`